# Windows is not present in grub menu

Tags: system, dual-boot, microsoft-windows, release-odin, uefi

(I don't know if this question belongs here, but here we go)

I bought a new HP 14(2021) last week, with 11th gen core i3 and Xe graphics. It came with Windows 10. After a few days, I installed Manjaro on it, along with windows but Manjaro had some problems booting up. I watched a few YT tutorials and found out that it could be associated with grub.

Yesterday, I booted into a live user in manjaro and was gonna fix grub. There was a part in which I would have to mount the root partition of Manjaro, but I accidentally mounted the Windows partition. Then, I was trying to unmount it, but the partition was busy, so I powered off the pc. I turned on the lap again, but the grub menu was not shown and it directly booted into Manjaro, which had some rootfs problems.

Then, I installed elementary os, without formatting the efi, but the grub menu still didn't show Windows. I checked the uefi firmware, and it still showed windows boot manager. On selecting it, a grub rescue screen was shown. From elementary, I tried os-prober and update-grub, but both didn't show the windows partition.

The EFI partition currently has manjaro,windows boot manager,ubuntu and elementary os. The last 2 came after installing EOS.

When I booted from the Windows 10 iso and executed some commands in the command prompt of the troubleshoot, it could not find any windows installation. So,has windows been uninstalled or is it some Linux related problem?
(I can still access files in the Windows Partition from Elementary)

P.S: The link of the video which I referred to:
https://youtu.be/8hxLIua8SS4?t=163

PPS: I am ready to install windows again, if required.

Comment: If Windows cannot find a Windows installation, there’s a good chance the OS has been wiped off the machine. If you decide to re-install Windows, be advised that it needs to go on the machine first, then you’ll need to resize partitions to make space for a Linux installation. Windows does not like to share a computer with other OSes 

Comment: I still have the windows partition there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue not directly related to eOS, and so you are probably better off asking at other (more frequented) places, or searching those places for an answer. This post on Ask Ubuntu might be what you are looking for: https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix

If that doesn't work or would take too much time (plus you've mentioned a clean install not being a problem), I would just format the whole disk and start with a fresh install of Win 10 (or 11), and take it from there.

Comment: BTW, the windows installation had ms office in it, so is there any way to get them back?

PS: Thanks for the reply

Comment: You are welcome! As far as I know, new installations of Office are tied to your Microsoft account, and so you should be able to install it without a problem after signing in.